# SetAccuracy behavior

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I'm puzzled by the output I get from `SetAccuracy`. According to the documentation, when `SetAccuracy` is used to increase the accuracy of a number, the number is padded with zeros.
But, let's take a look at a couple of examples:

```
SetAccuracy[1.2, 5]
(* 1.2000 *)
SetAccuracy[1., 5]
(* 1.0000 *)
SetAccuracy[0.2, 5]
(* 0.2000 *)
```

These examples seem to work properly, so why does it behave differently in this case?

```
SetAccuracy[0., 5]
(* 0.*10^-5 *)
```

What should I do to get a zero with four trailing zeros?

**Update**
I'm asking this question, because I need to export data to a txt file and I would like to avoid having `0.*10^-5` sort of numbers.

Comment: SetAccuracy is not a formatting tool, but intended to set accuracy of numeric value(s). How about something like `PaddedForm[0., {4, 4}]`?

Comment: @kirma It might work, but it creates other problems if I try to export the data.

Comment: What other problems?

Comment: `NumberForm[0., {1, 4}]` will print `0.0000`

Comment: @Rojo Look at the exported document: `Export["test.txt", PaddedForm[RandomReal[], {4, 4}]]`.

Comment: Does Export["test.txt", StandardForm@PaddedForm[RandomReal[], {4, 4}]] work for you ?

Comment: @image_doctor Partially, it inserts an empty space in the exported doc. It is better with `StandardForm@NumberForm[0., {4, 4}]`. But then again, it is not generic: `StandardForm@NumberForm[1200345., {10, 4}] `.

Comment: @image_doctor Maybe this workaround solves the problem:`StandardForm@
 NumberForm[1200345., {10, 4}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]`. I'll check it now extensively.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments by image_doctor led me to the answer I was looking for:

```
StandardForm@NumberForm[1.2, {20, 4}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
(* 1.2000 *)
StandardForm@NumberForm[1., {20, 4}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
(* 1.0000 *)
StandardForm@NumberForm[0.2, {20, 4}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
(* 0.2000 *)
StandardForm@NumberForm[0., {20, 4}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
(* 0.0000 *)
```

The data are then consistent and can be easily exported.

Comment: You would think this workaround could be invoked via an `Export` option.

Answer (score 3):

Might want to have a look at the InputForm of these.

```
SetAccuracy[0., 5] // InputForm

(*Out[38]//InputForm = 0``5.*)

SetAccuracy[1.2, 5] // InputForm

(*Out[39]//InputForm=1.19999999999999995559107901499373838305`5.079181246047625*)
```

I doubt either gives the behavior you are after. As was suggested in a comment, maybe NumberForm or PaddedForm will meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

An example that allows you to accomplish your goal of exporting to a file without needing SetAccuracy is as follows:

```
Export["test.txt", ToString@NumberForm[#, {5, 4}] & /@ {RandomReal[], 0.0}]]
FilePrint["test.txt"]

Out[40]= "test.txt"

0.6538
0.0000
```