# How can I control the number format of exported data?

Tags: export, data, display

I'm having issues while exporting a tables of numerical values to "*.dat" data files.

Here's the thing, **sometimes** when I export a table, I get *more* decimals on some **random values**. The problem is that they weren't even there in the first place.

Now, for the sake of illustration, here's a **very simple** example on the issue. I tried constructing the following table :

```
Table[t, {t, 0, 0.4, 0.1}]
```

Which provides with the following list :

```
{0., 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, \
0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22, \
0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, \
0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4}
```

Now, I just tried to export it using the `Export`command like this :

```
Export["t.dat", Table[t, {t, 0, 0.4, 0.1}], "Table"]
```

and everything should be fine, but when you try to read what's in "t.dat" using `FilePrint` :

```
FilePrint["t.dat"]
```

I get the following :

0.
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.1
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15
0.16
0.17
0.18
0.19
0.2
0.21
0.22
0.23
0.24
0.25
0.26
0.27
0.28
0.29
0.3
0.31
0.32
0.33
0.34
0.35000000000000003
0.36
0.37
0.38
0.39
0.4

Note that the number 0.35 suddenly became 0.35000000000000003, which messes everything up. Is there something to solve this issue? I tried using the `NumberForm` function but it changes the structure of the exported list...

What I intend to do is to export **t** list presented above, alongside with *another* list in which I do operations using the values of the first one. For example :

```
time = Table[NumberForm[i, 6], {i, 0, 0.2, 0.01}];
op = Table[time[[i]]^2 + time[[i]], {i, 1, Length@time}];
Export["data.dat",Transpose@{time,op}, "Table"];
FilePrint["data.dat"];
```

Which returns :

```
0.  NumberForm[0., 6] + NumberForm[0., 6]^2
0.01    NumberForm[0.01, 6] + NumberForm[0.01, 6]^2
0.02    NumberForm[0.02, 6] + NumberForm[0.02, 6]^2
0.03    NumberForm[0.03, 6] + NumberForm[0.03, 6]^2
0.04    NumberForm[0.04, 6] + NumberForm[0.04, 6]^2
0.05    NumberForm[0.05, 6] + NumberForm[0.05, 6]^2
0.06    NumberForm[0.06, 6] + NumberForm[0.06, 6]^2
0.07    NumberForm[0.07, 6] + NumberForm[0.07, 6]^2
0.08    NumberForm[0.08, 6] + NumberForm[0.08, 6]^2
0.09    NumberForm[0.09, 6] + NumberForm[0.09, 6]^2
0.1 NumberForm[0.1, 6] + NumberForm[0.1, 6]^2
0.11    NumberForm[0.11, 6] + NumberForm[0.11, 6]^2
0.12    NumberForm[0.12, 6] + NumberForm[0.12, 6]^2
0.13    NumberForm[0.13, 6] + NumberForm[0.13, 6]^2
0.14    NumberForm[0.14, 6] + NumberForm[0.14, 6]^2
0.15    NumberForm[0.15, 6] + NumberForm[0.15, 6]^2
0.16    NumberForm[0.16, 6] + NumberForm[0.16, 6]^2
0.17    NumberForm[0.17, 6] + NumberForm[0.17, 6]^2
0.18    NumberForm[0.18, 6] + NumberForm[0.18, 6]^2
0.19    NumberForm[0.19, 6] + NumberForm[0.19, 6]^2
```

What I mean by "changes its structure" is the fact that I can no longer operate on the *time* list and its values correctly...

Comment: Some useful [background reading](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: @cormullion Reading it...

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13848/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, but in fact, I just found the answer to my problem... I could post the answer, but it is so trivial that I doubt it can be helpful to anybody... Should I close/delete my question? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Post it anyway, if you like. You can't close your own question, but you can delete it. My suggestion is to post your answer and then we will close it as too localized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, the answer to my question was trivial...

Instead of using `NumberForm` on the *time* list to operate, I just needed to export using **another** `NumberForm` version of the *time* list to operate... like *time2*... pretty easy...

```
time = Table[i, {i, 0, 0.4, 0.01}];
time2 = Table[NumberForm[i, 6], {i, 0, 0.4, 0.01}];
op = Table[time[[i]]^2 + time[[i]], {i, 1, Length@time}];
Export["data.dat", Transpose@{time2, op}, "Table"];
FilePrint["data.dat"];
```

which finally gives what I needed :

```
    0.  0.
0.01    0.0101
0.02    0.0204
0.03    0.0309
0.04    0.0416
0.05    0.0525
0.06    0.0636
0.07    0.0749
0.08    0.0864
0.09    0.0981
0.1 0.11
0.11    0.1221
0.12    0.1344
0.13    0.1469
0.14    0.1596
0.15    0.1725
0.16    0.1856
0.17    0.1989
0.18    0.2124
0.19    0.2261
0.2 0.24
0.21    0.2541
0.22    0.2684
0.23    0.2829
0.24    0.2976
0.25    0.3125
0.26    0.3276
0.27    0.3429
0.28    0.3584
0.29    0.3741
0.3 0.39
0.31    0.4061
0.32    0.4224
0.33    0.4389
0.34    0.4556
0.35    0.4725
0.36    0.4896
0.37    0.5069
0.38    0.5244
0.39    0.5421
0.4 0.56
```

Comment: This still look terrible at some places...

Answer (score 5):

`NumberForm` seems fine for the example you give:-

```
Export["t1.dat", Table[t, {t, 0.3, 0.4, 0.01}], "Table"];
Export["t2.dat", Table[NumberForm[t, 2], {t, 0.3, 0.4, 0.01}], "Table"];
TableForm[ReadList["!diff t1.dat t2.dat", "String"]]

(*
4,5c4,5
< 0.32999999999999996
< 0.33999999999999997
---
> 0.33
> 0.34
*)
```