# How to apply multiple format to a list

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, printing

I have a nested list like

```
matrix = {{1.2345664, 2.38673956, 3.567846}, {0.00034554, 124.4554654,
6.34543}, {0.0000233, 244.34454, 2}}
```

and I want to apply `MatrixForm`, but also `NumberForm[,{5,4}]`, because I want that in every element of the matrix the numbers are properly padded.

Is this possible in some way?

Interestingly perhaps, I want eventually write the resulting output list in a file.

P.S.: Now I write with `Export["my_file.dat",Flatten[matrix]]`, and after I obtain the proper padding using a C program. But there must be a clever way...

Comment: Are you going to manipulate the matrix further ? `MatrixForm[Table[NumberForm[matrix[[i, j]], {5, 4}] , {i, 3}, {j, 3}]]` will do what you want but then you cannot, for instance, take `Det` or `Inverse`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks No, I don't want to manipulate further the matrix, but I have problems in writing in a file if I don't use `Export` (I want to write in append mode so I'm using `PutAppend`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a couple of different ways.  This is easiest:

```
NumberForm[MatrixForm @ matrix, {5, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works because `NumberForm` affects sub-expressions including ones wrapped in `MatrixForm`.  You can do it the other way but it's more complicated:

```
Map[NumberForm[#, {5, 4}] &, matrix, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

You mention that you eventually want to export this.  You should not need (or use) `MatrixForm` for export.  The question of export of `NumberForm` formatted numbers may be answered here:  [How can I control the number format of exported data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20385/121)  In version 7 however the Accepted answer does not work.  You might use something like:

```
Export[
 "myfile.dat"
 Map[ToString @ NumberForm[#, {5, 4}] &, matrix, {2}],
 "Table"
]
```

Comment: I want to write in append mode, so I'm using `PutAppend` for writing, but in this case your solution doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @Fabrizio Could you be more specific?  Ideally, post the code that isn't working, *and* the expected output.

Comment: The code is simply `PutAppend[NumberForm[MatrixForm@matrix, {5, 4}], outFile]`, and the required output is the usual.

Comment: @Fabrizio Sorry, I didn't see your comment until today.  It may be best to use `WriteString` as `Put` is better suited to writing expressions rather than formatted output.  For example:  `str = OpenWrite["numform.dat"];  
WriteString[str, NumberForm[Grid @ matrix, {5, 4}]];  
Close[str];`  -- does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also I have now learned that is better convert expressions in strings before writing them in a file.