# How to avoid rounding error, when exporting numerical values

Tags: export, numerical-value

How to avoid the rounding error, when exporting data like this:

```
ra = Range[0.004, 0.074, 0.0005];
Export["range.txt", ra]
```

The result is this:
[image]

Comment: Why? When you read this data with another program that uses floating point, the error will grow back anyway.

Comment: This is just an example, but it inflates the size of my files unnecessarily. As I am handling a huge amount of data I have to figure out some efficiency.

Comment: Try something like `ToString@NumberForm[#, {10, 4}] & /@ ra` before exporting. Does that help?

Comment: Alternatively to @halirutan's suggestion, you can use `Export["range.txt", NumberForm[ra, {10, 4}], "List"]`

Comment: Also, [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20385/how-can-i-control-the-number-format-of-exported-data) is strongly related

Comment: *but it inflates the size of my files unnecessarily* If size is an issue why are you not writing binary files ?  Not only will that ensmallen your files, it will circumvent the problem which prompted your question, and make reading/writing faster. Win win win.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) on your list, `ra`.

```
ExportString[SetPrecision[ra, 6], "Table"]
```

> ```
> 0.004
> 0.0045
> 0.005
> 0.0055
> 0.006
> 0.0065
> 0.007
> 0.0075
> 0.008
> 0.0085
> 0.009
> 0.0095
> 0.01
> 0.0105
> ...
> ```

Hope this helps.